# Update android apk and app description

Tags: android, google-play-services

I need to update android application i.e apk and app description.
Do I need to update twice ? I mean click on SUBMIT UPDATE button twice ?

Click 1 under "Release Management - App releases" option. [Updates apk]

Click 2 under "Store Presence - Store Listing" option.    [Updates app description]

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you're submitting an update for two separate things.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It can be done on any order right ? ..  I am planning to do back to back. I am worried because it should not effect production.

Comment: You can update the app description any time you want to.You can upload an APK and just not roll it out to production until you're ready

Comment: Any order is fine, Google Play updates it's store listings and sends APK updates to users very fast now, both get updated within about 10/15 minutes. I wouldn't be too worried about it, you'll see its quite a simple process when you're done.